# JQuery - get a variable from the URL to set a CSS value

Tags: jquery, css, url

I wrote this code in order to set the text color of an active menu item:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var url = window.location.href;
var pieces = url.split("?whatPage=");

$('#pieces[1]').css('color', 'red');
});
```

If I alert `pieces[1]` I get the value of the ID of the relevant menu item, but the menu item's color is unaffected. What is most likely to be going wrong?

Comment: you use your variable as your selector-**string**, you have to concatenate them: `$('#' + pieces[1])`

Comment: thanks, I understand. Changed it, but it doesn't work yet ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `$('#pieces[1]').css('color', 'red');`

try :

```
$('#'+pieces[1]).css('color', 'red');
```

Comment: Hmm tried, but that wasn't it, or at least there is something else incorrect apparently .. 
Is there perhaps something more fundamentally wrong with my idea, or should it work?

Comment: Maybe you don't have the element with that id on the page.

Comment: actually I do ..
   <a id="<?php echo $cols[1];?>menu item</a>

I checked page source and it is similar to an alert of pieces[1]

Comment: Can you share the HTML and CSS(if any)

Comment: so there  is no CSS, just the custom one I try to apply to the a-tag.

Comment: You can see the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/632/ It's working. Something might be wrong in your case/

Comment: I checked, and I do see there is a space at the end of id=" " .. Pretty sure that's causing my trouble ..

Comment: You can trim those spaces if they are creating issues

Comment: yes, I just found out. Trimming + concatenate on selector solved this